# Vout NMOS CS amplifier LTspice simulation

Tags: amplifier, ltspice, simulation, nmos

I've been trying to create this 2 block cs amplifier for a 5V/V gain. The problem is that my Vout is saturated on both cycles, and I do not know why this is happening.

The transistor used is NMOS 2N7002 polarized with 62mA and Vgs = 2.5V.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Reduce the input amplitude until you get a sine wave out to find out your actual gain. Your 1F capacitors are not very practical.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening right now is that your 2nd stage is amplifying the DC output of your 1st stage as well as your AC signal. Therefore, you get saturation in your 2nd stage.

Plot the waveform before your output capacitor (M2 drain) and see where your bias point is. It won't be the same as the gate of the M2.

Since you're using local series-series feedback (so-called "emitter/source degeneration") in both stages, then it is better that you AC couple both stages as well. You should add a capacitor in series with the output of your 1st stage, and then fix the gate voltage of your 2nd stage with a resistive divider (just like you do for your 1st stage).

Answer (score 2):

Your actual gain is about 15 so a 1V input will cause the output to saturate.

With the output stage bias you have (about 7V at the drain) and a single 9V supply you can't expect to get more output p-p than you have.

You've got 1 farad capacitors everywhere, which is okay for simulation.. if you allow the initial operating point calculation.. but not very practical. If you have a more practical 1uF in those positions, the impedance at 100Hz will be so high (especially on the MOSFET source capacitors) that you'll probably have overall gain < 1.

You can split the source resistors and bypass only part of them to add some degeneration and control the gain of each stage.